# How to plot longitude and lattitude in react js for making my own custom map without using any api like google map and leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps

I am making my own custom map where  longitude and lattitude are provided from admin side and needed to be rendered on the client side to make my own map ? i searched but all sites are showing me the reference of leaflet or google map but i wonder how to create on my own . Any idea?

Comment: to make this you would need a reference point of the world map where you have a detailed description of the places. In google maps reference they constantly use GPS system which has its own satellite to provide detailed images. On zoom these coordinates are converted into 128x128 by screen to prevent stack overflow. You can not do this if you don't have access to maps by google maps or leaflet. I am not sure if GPS provides open api for security reasons but you can check how you can get access. It will be a hefty payment in my experience

Comment: i am having problem on plotting the coordinates and joining them to make a map -coordinates of location i already know